# Extracting chmod file permissions in PHP

Tags: php, notifications, chmod

I come with a problem. Well, I wanted to make notifications about too high chmod file. Here is the code I wrote:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed!');
$errors = FALSE;
$config_file = "config.php";

if(is_writeable(APPPATH.'config/'.$config_file)) {
    $errors = TRUE; 
    $_SESSION['chmod_error'] = "<div class='notification is-danger' style='padding:12px;'><i class='fa fa-times'></i> Configuration file (".$config_file.") is writeable!</div>";
} else {
    $_SESSION['chmod_error'] = "<div class='notification is-success' style='padding:12px;'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Configuration file (".$config_file.") is not writeable</div>";
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work properly. It still displays the same error even if the chmods are set to **777** or **644**.

Photo here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXMKC.png

Is there a way to "get" what chmod file has? And can you show an error if the file has a **higher chmod than eg 644?** If so, how do you do it?

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry, but my English is not perfect, so I have to help myself Google Translate :D

Comment: You've got your condition backwards. You show an error when `is_readable` returns true and success when it returns false.

Comment: The same applies even after you've changed it to `is_writeable`.

Comment: This code(→) works very well. In the end I was able to solve this problem :D https://pastebin.com/p95DLr0Q